# How do I determine if a type is memcpy-save?

Tags: c++, memcpy, type-traits

I work with colleagues who like `memcpy` (too) much. I am porting code which generally deals with simple types (`double`s mostly), which can be safely copied using `memcpy`, extending it to non-trivial types. I wanted to write a simple copy function which does the right thing depending on the type in question:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
void fancy_copy(const T* src,
                T* dest,
                unsigned int size)
{
  // here:
  if(std::is_trivially_copy_assignable<T>::value)
  {
    memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(T) * size);
  }
  else
  {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
      dest[i] = src[i];
    }
  }
}

class Custom
{
private:
  int value;
public:
  Custom& operator=(const Custom& other)
  {
    value = other.value + 1;
    return *this;
  }
};

int main()
{
  const unsigned int size = 10;

  {
    std::vector<int> source(size, 0);
    std::vector<int> target(size, 0);

    fancy_copy<int>(source.data(), target.data(), size);
  }

  {
    std::vector<Custom> source(size);
    std::vector<Custom> target(size);

    fancy_copy<Custom>(source.data(), target.data(), size);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I used the `type_traits` built into C++ in order to determine which implementation to use. Unfortunately, when I compile the code with `-Wall` using `g++` (10.2) i get the warning

```
warning: ‘void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)’ writing to an object of type ‘class Custom’ with no trivial copy-assignment; use copy-assignment or copy-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess]
```

So, for my `Custom` class, `memcpy` is being incorrectly used. Which type trait do I need to use to select the correct operation and silence the warning?

Comment: [Some handy reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable).

Comment: I think you have this error because even if `is_trivially_copy_assignable` is false the compiler still sees `memcpy` code. Have you tried using [std::enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) instead?

Comment: [is_trivially_copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) tells you if it can be memcopied

Comment: *"a simple copy function which does the right thing"* - I'd call it `std::copy`. Standard library implementers typically optimizes such common algorithms very very well.

Comment: Btw, doesn't C++ do memcpy as a default copy anyway?

Comment: @freakish: No. As StoryTeller correctly notes, `std::copy` really is the default copy. It works with all copyable types, and often is optimized. It can even beat `memcpy` because `memcpy` has to support unaligned copies too. But `double` to `double` is aligned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct type trait to use for this is [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable), not `std::is_trivially_copy_assignable`.

To fix the warning, use [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) instead of `if` in order to perform the check at compile time and only generate one of the two branches as unconditional logic for a given type `T`. Even if an ill-formed call is unreachable due to runtime conditional logic, the warning is emitted by the compiler because the call still exists in the generated code.

Also consider using [`std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) from `<algorithm>` to simplify your logic for the fallback.

Try it on godbolt.org: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vEfKhE).

For C++11, you can use [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to select which implementation to use at compile time similar to C++17 `if constexpr`:

```cpp
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value>::type
fancy_copy(const T* src, T* dest, unsigned int size)
{
  memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(T) * size);
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value>::type
fancy_copy(const T* src, T* dest, unsigned int size)
{
  std::copy_n(src, size, dest);
}
```

Try it on godbolt.org: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xhKzvz).

Ultimately though, as others have pointed out, this `fancy_copy` might be a premature optimization, and you would be better off just using `std::copy_n` where semantically correct, allowing the compiler to perform its own optimizations. Compare the binary between [`fancy_copy`](https://godbolt.org/z/xr586s) and [`std::copy_n`](https://godbolt.org/z/j9cjoe) when using `-O3` to see for yourself. They're exactly identical.

Comment: I did not even know about `constexpr if `. Is there any way to achieve the same for pre-C++17?

Comment: @hfhc2 are you using C++11 or 14?

Comment: Well, I am afraid I am resigned to C++11

Comment: @hfhc2 no worries, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes. `std::copy_n` is extremely fast, and sometimes faster than `memcpy` when the compiler can compute the alignment

Comment: This should maybe be the take away. Still using memcpy in C++ code is just cargo cult programming.